# Web Service with Java 1.6 and Tomcat6 in Debian / Linux

Tags: java, web-services, debian, tomcat6, jdeveloper

I tried to develop a very simple Java WebService with Jdeveloper 12 (a single string variable with getter and setter). I tried debugging it on Windows and all went fine (I can get and set the values on the variable).

I created the "`.war`" file but when I try to develop to tomcat (with basic configuration)

I can't see it on available webservices nor I can't access it...

I'm trying to develop it on `Debian 6.0.7`.

I didn't find the settings to change the port where the webservice is listening on too.

I'll accept tutorial with Eclipse or Netbeans.

Does anyone know a guide or a complete tutorial from the developing to the deploy of the web service? I need to know how to configure the various `.xml` files to let it working..

Answer (score 0):

I Assume you are trying to deploy to tomcat. Have you used any frameworks to convert your java program into a web service? Is there any " .wsdl " file which you can locate?

1. Create a java class with a string variable setter and getter
2. Expose this class as a webservice (Can be done by any frameworks ex: axis, cxf etc.)
3. The framework provides with a wsdl file and a war if you built it.
4. Then deploy war file to any server.

Did you miss the points 2 & 3 ?